# New to Pandas, need to create a df from 2 others (not a merge)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of hotels with some attributes (a1, a2, a3, a4):

```
hotel   date    a1        a2       a3       a4
H1      201501  business  couple   pool     no kid
H2      201501  NaN       couple   pool     NaN
H3      201502  NaN       couple   beach    kids
```

I also have a list of room types linked to some attributes.

```
id   rooms    a1        a2     a3
AAA  single   business
BBB  double   couple
BBB  double   man       woman
CCC  triple   family
CCC  triple   couple    kid
```

Each option (single, double, triple) is linked to a combination of attributes (a1, a2, a3, ...)
For instance, (couple) or (man + woman) will bring option 'double'.
So, hotel H1 get single and double rooms.

**How can I create a new DataFrame with those options?**
per hotel, like:

```
hotel   date    single  double  triple
H1      201501  1       1       0
H2      201501  0       1       0
H3      201502  0       1       1
```

I did all that in plain python easily, with a simple data_model, but I would like to do some statistics later, so I try to use pandas.

thanks for helping!

### EDIT

I add a simple python (without panda) sample

```
hotels = [{'hotel':'H1', 'date':201501, 'attributes': ['business', 'couple', 'pool', 'no_kid']},
          {'hotel':'H2', 'date':201501, 'attributes': ['NaN', 'couple', 'pool', 'NaN']},
          {'hotel':'H3', 'date':201502, 'attributes': ['NaN', 'couple', 'beach', 'kids']}]
rooms = {'single':[['business']],
         'double':[['couple'], ['man', 'woman']],
         'triple':[['family'], ['couple', 'kids']]}
for hotel in hotels:
    hotel['rooms']=[]
    att_set = set(hotel['attributes'])
    for room, combi in rooms.iteritems():
        for tags in combi:
            tags_set = set(tags)
            if tags_set.issubset(att_set):
                hotel['rooms'].append(room)
    del(hotel['attributes'])
print hotels

[{'date': 201501,
  'hotel': 'H1',
  'rooms': ['double', 'single']},
 {'date': 201501,
  'hotel': 'H2',
  'rooms': ['double']},
 {'date': 201502,
  'hotel': 'H3',
  'rooms': ['double', 'triple']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One cannot answer your question without merging the lists, and as you don't provide a foreign key linking them, the merge cannot be done. However, counting can be done quite easily with groupby:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
from pandas import DataFrame

TESTDATA=StringIO("""hotel   date    a1        a2       a3       a4
H1      201501  business  couple   pool     no_kid
H2      201501  NaN       couple   pool     NaN
H3      201502  NaN       couple   beach    kids
""")

df = DataFrame.from_csv(TESTDATA, sep=r"[ ]+")

df.reset_index().groupby(['hotel','date','a3']).size().unstack('a3').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried it, but you last line does not seems to modify df. I use pandas 0.14.1. I added a plain python sample to my question, maybe it's more clear

Comment: Of course not. I meant it for you to check it interactively (in IPython?). You need to assign it to a variable. Like df2 = df.reset...

Comment: ok, sorry. I though it would modify df. So, I went to read about groupby, but still doesn't make the job :) I am afraid that my question was not that clear, so, I added a small plain python sample, if you still have time, please, have a look. thanks again.

Comment: of course, I can build my DataFrame like I built my dict: "by hand". But I thought that from the magic of pandas, I could do it in a "pandas" way :)